# <p:commandLink> not firing actions at all

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I can't make my commandLink fire a bean action.

I've tried calling my bean method with `<p:commandButton>`, `<h:commandLink>`, `<h:outputLink>` and `<p:commandLink>`.

Also, i've used `onclick`, `onmousedown`, `action` and `actionListener` and none of those worked.
My code looks like this at the moment:

base.xhtml

```
<div>
    <h:form>
        <p:commandLink id="logoutButton" action="#{loginController.logout}">
            <p:graphicImage name="/images/logout.png"/>
        </p:commandLink>
    </h:form>

    <!-- Rest of code (layout with some layoutUnits) -->
</div
```

Bean method (Testing purposes, not the actual method):

```
public void logout() {
    System.out.println("logged out");
}
```

According to BalusC, my question is duplicated. I had already searched for similar problems before making this question, and guess what? Nothing worked. Looking at same question that has already been answered, here are my answers to the previously described problems:

1 - The commandLink is inside a `form`.

2 - The commandLink is not in a nested `form`.

3 - No UIInput value validation/conversion is showing errors.

4 - The commandLink is not inside a iterating component.

5 - As the pages load, the button is not rendered. I've set it to render only if the user log-ins with a commandLink placed in that same form. It is indeed using AJAX.

6 - The onclick attribute of the UICommand component and the onsubmit attribute of the UIForm are not throwing a JavaScript error.

7 - `base.xhtml` has a `<h:head>`

8 - The parent of my `<h:form>` is not being updated/rendered.

9 - Im not using `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in my form.

10 - I'm not using `actionListener`.

11 - I'm not using `PhaseListener` or `EventListener`.

12 - There is no `Filter` or `Servlet` blocking the request to the FacesServlet.

Bonus:

- Debugging with Firebug, i've noticed that when i click the logout button i'm getting a code 200 response from the server, meaning it is `supposed` to be OK.
- My form is in a Template file (base.xhtml). After that form, i am using a `<p:layout>` element and my website code is inside it's `<p:layoutUnit>`.

[image: a]
[image: b]
[image: c]

Comment: index.html or xhtml? Did you get any exception? Or Script Errors?

Comment: You may find your answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2120183/634958

Comment: If you had appended a *minimal example*, we could have helped you possibly.

Comment: iMmo - actually it is base.XHTML... i've edited my question now.

Comment: S1LENT WARRIOR - Check my updated question. I've already searched a LOT before posting this.

Comment: Because i've tested without EVERYTHING in my xhtml. I tried removing every element and just leaving the login AND logout button  rendered by default and it still didn't work.

Comment: When i get home i will provide some screenshots of my project to see if it helps.

Comment: What i've described above is a MCVE. My code looks 95% like what is stated, the only difference is that my login button is a `<p:commandButton>` (and works). Only my logout button doesn't work.

Comment: Why do you have both @ManagedBean and @Named? AFAIK thats a bad idea. Get rid of Named for JSF beans, or get rid of ManagedBean and change package of RequestScoped for CDI